# Getting CORS error even though I have cors installed and headers are set

Tags: node.js, express, cors

In my entry file, I have used cors() and also set headers to negotiate with cors errors. But when I try to set the header on another file payment.js for the post request, I am getting cors error.

I also imported payment.js in entry point server.js.

I am not getting what went wrong.

Thank you in advance

```
Error I am getting 


Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.43.147:4000/payment-check' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:4200' that is not equal to the supplied origin
```

This is my entry point server.js

```
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

const routes = require('./payment/ordersapi');
app.use(routes);

const payments = require('./payment/payment');
app.use(payments);


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200', 'http://localhost:8100');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

payment.js // another file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const router = express.Router();
app.use('/', router);   

router.post('/payment-check', function(req,res ) {

    var options = req.body
    console.log(options)

    var payment_id = options.razorpay_payment_id
    res.setHeader('payment_id' ,payment_id)
    res.redirect('http://localhost:8100/order-success')


})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What’s the exact error message that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: I have edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yow Broh! you are using router and even exporting it, but u neva declared it. 
[image]

Comment: Please do not include images of code in your answer. In this case, you could even exclude the code/image altogether and it would still answer the question. Also keep slang to a minimum.